# KnpMenuBuilder dropdownlist in menu (Bootstrap)

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my current web application I am making use of KnpMenuBuilder and Bootstrap to make a menu. I want to add an unordered list to a list item element, so that it appears as a dropdown menu, just like the [example(s)](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) given in the Bootstrap documentation. For this I should also add a `dropdown-menu` class to this `<ul></ul>` tag. It should look something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
    ...
    </li>
    <li><!-- or this should be <li class="dropdown"> not entirely sure
        if this happens with javascript or something yet -->
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
            Dropdown
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>Dropdown menu item 1</li>
            <li>Dropdown menu item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I know you can add such element in the MenuBuilder class:

```
public function mainMenu(FactoryInterface $factory, array $options)
    {
        $menu = $factory->createItem('root', array(
            'childrenAttributes' => array(
                'class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
            ),
        ));

        $menu->addChild('Home', array('route' => 'home'));
        $menu->addChild('Movies', array('route' => 'movies'))
        ->setAttribute('class', 'dropdown');
        $menu['Movies']->addChild('Add a movie', array('route' => 'movie_create_form'));
        //This renders <li><a href="#">movies</a><ul><li><a href="#">Add a movie</a></li></ul></li>
        //I want to add the drop-down class to the <ul></ul> tag

        return $menu;
    }
```

My current result:

```
<!-- Ofcourse <ul> tag should be around this aswell, but my question is not about the beauty of this code -->
<li>...</li>
<li dropdown="dropdown" class="active last">
    <a href="#">
        Dropdown
    </a>
    <ul class="menu_level_1">
        <li class="first last">
            <a href="#">
                Dropdown menu item 1
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Or: http://pastebin.com/XHyYeWer

(original: http://pastebin.com/gnK2G0uz)

How should I change my (builder class) code?

Thanks in advance.